# Getting error when installing Mautic

Tags: php, mautic, cloudways

I am getting this error

> PHP version 5.6.x requires the PHP configuration directive
>   always_populate_raw_post_data be set to -1. This is handled
>   automatically by the .htaccess file when using Apache and mod_php5,
>   but must be set manually in php.ini for other server configurations.
>   Please add 'always_populate_raw_post_data = -1' to your php.ini and
>   restart your web server.

where installing mautic. I am using cloudways server. Any suggestion would help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily work around this issue by defining `php_admin_value[always_populate_raw_post_data] = -1` under Application Settings > PHP Settings and restarting PHP FPM from Manage Services. Afterwards, the installer will proceed and complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini of php-fpm and cli and add the line mentioned in the error.

Comment: Don't post your email address in the answer. If you want to answer - Answer for everyone to see